# Rotate element in steps of 45 degrees, always forward

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, rotatetransform

Let's say I want to animate rotate an UI element 45 degrees clockwise each time I press a button.

I have defined 8 visual states setting different `RotateTransform` values between them. So, whenever I press the button I move to the next visual state:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MyElement, "Position2", True)
```

etc.

The problem is that when moving from the VisualState 8 to VisualState 1, the element rotates backward. Seems logical, since it is moving from 315º to 0º.

The question is, how could achieve to goal of always moving forward when pressing the button?

Comment: Instead of declaring 8 states, add 45degrees to the previous state, each time

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo , I have thought about it, but I don't know, and I can't find how I could add 45º to the current RotateTransform property in Visual Basic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple example for you in C#; VB should be very similar.

In your Main Window put a `Rectangle` and a `Button`. Then, set the `RenderTransformOrigin` for the `Rectangle` like in the Xaml sample.

In your code behind, declare your `RotateTransform` and attach it to the `Rectangle` as shown below. Everytime the `Button` is pressed, the `Angle` property of the `RotateTransform` is increased of 45.

**@EDIT:**
I like @Clemens formula to increase angle (it avoid overflows). I edited my answer.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myRect" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightBlue" >

    </Rectangle>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="10" Click="Button_Click">Rotate</Button>
</Grid>
```

**Window Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TransformGroup _transformGroup;
    private RotateTransform _rotateTrsf;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        _rotateTrsf = new RotateTransform();
        _transformGroup.Children.Add(_rotateTrsf);

        SetupAnimation();

        myRect.RenderTransform = _transformGroup;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _rotateAnimation.To = Math.Floor(_rotateTrsf.Angle / 45 + 1) * 45;            
        _rotateTrsf.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, _rotateAnimation);
        _rotateAnimation.From = _rotateAnimation.To;            
    }

    private void SetupAnimation()
    {           
        _rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        _rotateAnimation.From = 0.0;
        _rotateAnimation.To = 45;
        _rotateAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo. I have already figured it out. But how can I animate it?

Answer (score 3):

A basic example with animation could look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotation"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button Content="Rotate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

with this Button Click handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const double rotSpeed = 180; // °/s, i.e. 45° in 0.25 seconds

    var newAngle = Math.Floor(rotation.Angle / 45 + 1) * 45; // integer multiple of 45°
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((newAngle - rotation.Angle) / rotSpeed);

    rotation.BeginAnimation(
        RotateTransform.AngleProperty, new DoubleAnimation(newAngle, duration));
}
```